# Exporting an image for visualization (Earth Engine Python API)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-python-api

In a snippet from the documentation I can view elevation data in the code editor with the following:

```
var dataset = ee.Image('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30/V2_2');
var elevation = dataset.select('AVE_DSM');
var elevationVis = {
  min: -9999,
  max: 15355,
  palette: ['0000ff', '00ffff', 'ffff00', 'ff0000', 'ffffff'],
};
Map.setCenter(136.85, 37.37, 4);
Map.addLayer(elevation, elevationVis, 'Elevation');
```

The palette and min/max values are defined in a layer inside a map. How do I access them in Python?

So in the following code for export to drive, how would I make the DEM data be something useful? Right now its just a black mess since I can't control the visualization.

```
dataset = ee.Image('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30/V2_2').select('AVE_DSM')

task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(image=dataset, 
                                    description= 'Image',
                                    folder='BatchTest',
                                    region=[[-120, 35], [-119, 35], [-119, 34], [-120, 34]],
                                    scale=30,
                                    fileFormat='GeoTIFF')
task.start()
print(task.status())
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.visualize()` to export data as an 8-bit RGB image. Note that the image will no longer contain the original data values; each band of the image will represent color intensity for red, green, and blue respectively. If you want to maintain the original data, keep the export as you have it and use the visualization settings in your GIS to stretch a color palette to the min and max data values for the range in your region of interest.

```js
dataset = ee.Image('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30/V2_2') \
  .select('AVE_DSM') \
  .visualize(
    min=0,
    max=3000,
    palette=['0035F9', '34886A', '80B412', 'F1CA24', 'FD8814', 'FE4E41', 'FD92FA']
  )
```

[Learn more about image visualization](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization#visualization-images)